# Create varibles from CSV file

Tags: powershell

My computerlist is a CSV file with 3 columns (Machinename, New_AU, and New_State).

I'm trying to move each machine in my computer list to it's TargetOU. The TargetOU for each machine is based on the New_AU and New_State. I'm not sure how to get this information from the CSV file. Here is what I have so far. I appreciate any and all help on this matter.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Scripts\AUchange\Computerlist.csv"
$TargetOU = "OU=$New_AU,OU=$New_State,OU=ST,OU=EN,DC=en,DC=wb,DC=bk,DC=cp"

foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {
    Get-ADComputer $Computer | 
        Move-ADObject -Server AD-server.en.wb.bk.cp -TargetPath $TargetOU
}
```

Comment: Move the `$TargetOu =` inside the ForEach and change to `$TargetOU="OU=$Computer.New_AU,OU=$Computer.New_State,OU=ST,OU=EN,DC=en,DC=wb,DC=bk,DC=cp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK lets go over whats wrong.

The variables **$New_AU** and **$New_State** are not defined in script so right now there **Null**.

```
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Scripts\AUchange\Computerlist.csv
$TargetOU   =  "OU=$New_AU,OU=$New_State,OU=ST,OU=EN,DC=en,DC=wb,DC=bk,DC=cp"
```

Solution : I am going off the fact you said that your $ComputerList should be an Array of objects that contain multiable objects with the properties New_AU, New_State and MachineName

If thats the case you could use :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Scripts\AUchange\Computerlist.csv | %{
    $TargetOU = "OU=$($_.New_AU),OU=$($_.New_State),OU=ST,OU=EN,DC=en,DC=wb,DC=bk,DC=cp"
    Get-ADComputer $_.Machinename | Move-ADObject -Server AD-server.en.wb.bk.cp -TargetPath $TargetOU
}
```

What is happening

In powershell **|** means Pipe. This will send the data from the previous command to the next one in the pipe **|** and the variable for that data will be **$_**

So we Import-CSV which turns the file into a Powershell Object. We then Pipe **|** that object to a **%{}** which is shorthand for **ForEach-Object**

We set the **$TargetOU** with a string using **$()** which means expression (It means run this section as script not as string. Then we call the object data passed from **Import-CSV** using $_ and then call each property needed **$_.PropertyName**.

We then **Get-AdComputer** using the piped **|** data $_ with property **MachineName** that we got from **Import-csv**. We pipe that **Get-AdComputer** Object to **Move-ADObject** where we set the **-TargetPath** parameter to **$TargetOU**

Comment: Thanks ArcSet! Not just for the answer but also for the additional notes and education.